# Which version of devise suitable for rails 5.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Which version of devise suitable for rails 5.0.0, latest version of devise 3.5.6 does not support in rails 5.0.0

Comment: Can you please post error you got?

Comment: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    devise (= 3.5.6) was resolved to 3.5.6, which depends on
      railties (< 5, >= 3.2.6)

    rails (= 5.0.0) was resolved to 5.0.0, which depends on
      railties (= 5.0.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in their [README](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise):

> Devise 4.0 works with Rails 4.1 onwards

Run `bundle update` and see if devise changed to version 4 in your gemlock file

Comment: Is there any option to continue with devise 3.5.6 and rails 5.0.0

Comment: Why do you want to stick with 3.5.6 ?